# How to make a method inside a structure to display an array of it?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

So basically what I got stuck on is if I,for example, have a code like the one shown below then how should I construct the method in the structure in such order that it would display all N elements of structure when called.

```
struct MyStructure
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    public Method()
    {
        ?????????
    }
}
```

.....Main Section of program.....

```
MyStructure[] List=New MyStructure[N];
```

Comment: Not really. My school doesn't teach C#. It's a kind of self-training task but I've googled several tutorials and nobody covered an example similar to this.

Comment: You want to list the different fields of the structure? Look at [the reflection namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxz4wk15(v=vs.95).aspx). Otherwise, what you want doesn't make much sense!

Comment: @Bal that's because such things makes little sense. You can't see all the rooms in every room.. you can see all the rooms in one house. Same way when you have one list with many items, use the list itself to see those items, each item can't and should not know about the others.

Comment: I'm assuming the N here refers to the N elements in the array `New MyStructure[N];`

Answer (score 2):

An individual element is not the array, and unless you do something to *make* the array available, so element *will have access to the array. Rather - it will have access to itself (aka `thi

What you *could* do is make the method `static`:

```
public static void Method(IEnumerable<MyStructure> items)
{
    foreach(var item in items) Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
...
MyStructure.Method(List);
```

Side note (unrelated): I doubt that `struct` is the right choice here; it very rarely is... always default to `class` unless you can state **exactly why** you are making it a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add an instance method to an item contained *within* your array. It's probably better to use something like an extension method, e.g.:

```
public static void DisplayNames(this IEnumerable<MyStructure> items)
{
    foreach (MyStructure structure in items)
        Console.WriteLine(structure.Name);
}
```

Called as:

```
list.DisplayNames();
```

You could just use a normal static method, but I would question whether the process of displaying whatever information really relates to the purpose of the type itself, or whether the display process should be left to whatever types are consuming your structure.

Answer (score 0):

What you *might* be after is such  a thing, which does make some sense:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static List<MyClass> instances = new List<MyClass>();

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyClass(int id, string name)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        instances.Add(this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID = {0}, Name = {1}", this.ID, this.Name);
    }    

    public Method()
    {
        instances.ForEach(mc => Console.WriteLine(mc.ToString()));
    }
}
```

This will add every instance you create to global (static) list that is not attached to specific instance, then you can show/use this list whenever you want.

As others said, use `class`, not `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way how to do it using struct...

```
class Program
{
    public struct MyStructure
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void Method(int Current, int Total)
        {
            if (Current < Total)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(Current + ". " +  this.Name);
                this.Method(Current + 1, Total);
            };
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N = 100;
        MyStructure[] List = new MyStructure[N];
        List[0].Name = "Name";
        List[0].Method(0,N);
    }
}
```

just simple linked list...